# How to compare a specific column of two csv files?

Tags: python, csv

Let's say I have two csv files - `fileone` and `filetwo` - and both have columns [category, name, price, vendor]. In the `vendor` column, fileone has value "Georgia Malayv" and filetwo has value "Georgia". As you can see, `fileone` and `filetwo` both have "Georgia" as a value in the vendor column. I want the code to check column vendor, and I want a new csv file to print the values that are almost identical.

For example:

- `fileone` has these values:

  ```
  ['France', 'Pizza', 12.55, 'Georgia Malayv']
  ```
- `filetwo` has these values:

  ```
  ['Belgium', 'Steak', 15.99, 'Georgia']
  ```

If you look at the last values of both files, you see 'Georgia' is in both of them, but they are not equal to each other. How can I tell the computer that these lines are - according to me because both files have 'Georgia' - equal to each other and it can print the entire row of `filetwo`?

Can this be done? If I did not explain myself clearly enough, I will be happy to edit my question or answer yours. Here is what I tried:

```
with open('product1.csv', 'r') as mp, open('product2.csv', 'r') as yb:
    fileone = mp.readlines()
    filetwo = yb.readlines()

with open('update.csv', 'w') as outFile:
    for mp_item in fileone:
        for yb_item in filetwo:
            # mp_item[3] is the vendor column
            if mp_item[3] == True:
                outFile.write(mp_item)
```

This code did not print anything in the new csv file.

Comment: Is `mp_item[3]` actually `True`, or is it `'True'`?

Comment: @SuperStew I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: The line `if mp_item[3] == True:` means python will only write to the file if that element is `True`, which is a boolean value. But if just read it from a csv file, it likely is `'True'` which is a string that just looks boolean

Comment: @SuperStew it doesn't matter, that's not the test op wants to perform. it should be `if is_close_enough(mp_item[3], yb_item[3]):` sort of. (mp_item[3] is "Georgia Malayv")

Comment: the shortest name is always in filetwo or it's random?

Comment: bobrobbob is right. I need something along those lines. @bobrobbob It's random.

Comment: now you need to define what is "almost identical". with examples, if possible. and don't forget to edit your question: most people that answer questions don't read the comments

Comment: Is the comparison simply: Do the twp fields being compared contain any identical space-separated sequence of letters (i.e. words)?

Comment: @martineau I can't show you every value because there are 4000 of them total, but essentially, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
with open ("update.csv", "w") as output_file:
    for mp_item in fileOne:
        for yb_item in fileTwo: 
            shortest = min (mp_item [3], yb_item [3])
            longest = max (mp_item [3], yb_item [3])
            if shortest in longest: 
                outFile.write (mp_item)
```

This determines which is longer, which is shorter, and checks if the shorter one is in the longer one.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you for your answer, and thank you everyone else for your suggestions and helping me edit the question better!